# Where can I learn 2D game architecture

Tags: 2d, architecture, design-patterns

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Good resources for learning about game architecture?](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/455/good-resources-for-learning-about-game-architecture)

I know that game architecture can vary greatly, especially with the type of game being built, but I know that there are a lot of similarities too.

I feel like I am on the cusp of really having a good grasp on game architecture, but I feel like something is missing. Maybe it's something obvious. So, I want to know, is there a resource out there that is the be-all-end-all guide to 2D game programming concepts, patters and architecture?

**Edit:**  I'm mostly interested in building platformers and shmups and the like. So, if the resources are related to those types of games, even better.

Comment: There is no be-all-end-all guide. There are techniques and practices that people can use but at the end of the day a lot of it is totally subjective. What matters to your customers is the game, not the code.

Comment: @Tetrad - that may be true, but even if there isn't a perfect guide, there must be something that can teach basic architecture.

Comment: The amount that is 2D-specific in a 2D game engine - especially at the architectural level - is insignificant. You still need to load game data, process input, run a physics simulation, and in most cases texture polygons. That you're using Box2D and quads rather than Bullet and triangles doesn't matter. (In other words, this is already covered by every "best practices" question on this site.)