# References about Game Engine Architecture in AAA Games

Tags: education

Last weeks I focused on game engine architecture and learned a lot about different approaches like component based, data driven, and so on. I used them in test applications and understand their intention but none of them looks like the holy grail.

So I wonder how major games in the industry ("AAA Games") solve different architecture problems. But I noticed that there are barely references about game engine architecture out there.

Do you know any resources of game engine architecture of major game titles like Battlefield, Call of Duty, Crysis, Skyrim, and so on? Doesn't matter if it is an article of a game developer or a wiki page or an entire book.

I read this related popular question: [Good resources for learning about game architecture?](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/455/good-resources-for-learning-about-game-architecture) But it is focused on learning books rather than approaches in the industry.

Hopefully the breadth of our community can carry together certain useful informations! Thanks a lot!

Edit: This question is focused but not restricted to first person games.

Comment: You will have a hard time finding actual real references, because most of the AAA engines and their architecture details are under NDA's.

Comment: However, this question is overly broad and not reasonably answererable in its current form given the constraints of this site. You should only ask practical, answerable questions based on actual problems that you face. Please see the [FAQ](http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/faq) for details. Voting to close.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Book References**

- [http://www.amazon.com/dp/012229064X/](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/012229064X)
- [http://www.amazon.com/dp/1568814135/](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1568814135)
- [http://www.amazon.com/dp/0122290631/](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0122290631)
- http://www.gameenginebook.com/
- http://gameprogrammingpatterns.com/

**Community References**

- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1901251/component-based-game-engine-design
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1413863/insightful-resources-for-game-engine-architecture
- [Proposal for a game engine architecture (Adi's Game Dev Blog)](http://www.adi-jurca.com/my-proposal-for-a-game-engine-architecture/)

**Source Code References**

- http://fabiensanglard.net/doom3/index.php

Comment: I don't understand your so called basics references but anyway thanks for your book references!

Comment: @sharethis, basics renamed to Wikipedia references. Added just to review from Wikipedia. This reference may help others.

Comment: @sharethis, Added Source Code References. Those may help you.

Answer (score 0):

ID Software recently released the sourcecode of Doom 3 on Github: https://github.com/TTimo/doom3.gpl

There are also a lot of articles which analyzed it, like this one:
http://fabiensanglard.net/doom3/index.php

Comment: Even if Doom 3 is aged a bit, that is a nice reference!